# Promise: What happens to other async request when errors are thrown?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am using Bluebird promise. This isn't really explicit in the documentation. Suppose the following, assuming all the instances are appropriate promises:

```
FindSomeDBModel.then(function(model) {
    return [
        model.getOtherModels(),
        aHTTPRequest('https://google.com')
    ];
}).spread(function(otherModels, httpResponse) {
    // some code
}).catch(function(err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
});
```

1. If both `model.getOtherModels` and `aHTTPRequest` throws an error, what will be inside the `err` variable in the `catch`?
2. Also, what if `model.getOtherModels` throws an error first, will it cause a response to be sent out to the client or will it wait for `aHTTPRequest` to complete? Subsequently, `aHTTPRequest` throws, then what happens?
3. Can I respond back to the client as soon as one of the request throws an error? Because it is no longer material whether the other response completes and succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If both model.getOtherModels and aHTTPRequest throws an error, what will be inside the err variable in the catch?

An [`AggregateError`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#aggregateerror) would have been optimal but because of compatibility with `.all` which is specified outside of Bluebird and bluebird is compatibly with - it'll resolve with the *first* rejection up the chain.

In its own methods that don't need ES6 compatibility bluebird will return *all* the errors.

> Also, what if model.getOtherModels throws an error first, will it cause a response to be sent out to the client or will it wait for aHTTPRequest to complete? Subsequently, aHTTPRequest throws, then what happens?

It'll reject (and immediately enter the `catch`) as soon as the error is thrown, bluebird has a special case with `.spread` which checks if the argument passed is an array and calls `.all` on it - *this is a special case*, if you `.then`d it instead of `.spread`ing it that would not have happened.

> Can I respond back to the client as soon as one of the request throws an error? Because it is no longer material whether the other response completes and succeeds.

Yes, but consider using typed (or predicate) exceptions to have more meaningful error handling - if an error that's not an `OperationalError` happened you might want to restart the server.

Comment: Would `all`/`spread` really wait for all other promises after one was rejected? It should be rejected immediately and enter `catch` as soon as possible to my understanding.

Comment: No, but it can return an error for the first promise that is itself a promise (or an observable) for all the other promises :)

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to use an `AggregateError` if `all` was called on an array of already-rejected promises, or even if only one was rejected?

Comment: You reject when there are some pending promises and at least one rejected, it should return an observable or a promise for all the other rejections that'll happen. It does this for `some` but for `all` bluebird is spec bound

Comment: You mean you reject the promise with a promise that looks like an `Error`? Cool.

Comment: No, Thanks for clarifying that Bergi

Answer (score 2):

If an error occurs in one of those two promise executions, what will happen is

- the error is received in your `catch` callback
- the other promise is unaffected, its execution goes on
- the callback you gave to `spread` isn't called

If both `model.getOtherModels` and `aHTTPRequest` throw an error, only the first one will be received by `catch`, the other one will just be ignored.

The callback you gave to `catch` is called as soon as possible, when the first error is thrown, your code doesn't wait for the execution of the other one.

Comment: if i could accept 2 answers i would. this one is concise and simple. but i'm gonna go with benjamin's answer because it's a little more comprehensive. this is a good answer nonethless! thanks!